# Can I use shouldComponentUpdate in a PureComponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know the functionality for `shouldComponentUpdate` as well as `PureComponent`. But I'm wondering if I can use the two together?

Say I have lots of props which I want to let the shallow compare handle within `PureComponent`. Except 1 prop, which needs to be compared a bit cleverly. So is it possible to use `shouldComponentUpdate` for it? Which result would React consider?

In other words, would React call `PureComponent`'s shallow compare and then call my `shouldComponentUpdate`? or my `shouldComponentUpdate` would override the original one?

It would be nice if its two-layered, if `PureComponent` returns false, the control comes into my `shouldComponentUpdate` where I have another opportunity to `return false`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would first in the development environment get a warning as the [React source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d7157651f7b72d9888c0123e191f9b88cd8f41e9/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L301-L312) check to see if the method is defined or not when dealing with a `PureComponent`:

```
if (
  isPureComponent(Component) &&
  typeof inst.shouldComponentUpdate !== 'undefined'
) {
  warning(
    false,
    '%s has a method called shouldComponentUpdate(). ' +
      'shouldComponentUpdate should not be used when extending React.PureComponent. ' +
      'Please extend React.Component if shouldComponentUpdate is used.',
    this.getName() || 'A pure component',
  );
}
```

Then, when rendering, if this method is defined, it'll actually [skip](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d7157651f7b72d9888c0123e191f9b88cd8f41e9/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L902-L922) 
 and not even check if the component is a `PureComponent` and use your own implementation.

```
if (inst.shouldComponentUpdate) {
  if (__DEV__) {
    shouldUpdate = measureLifeCyclePerf(
      () => inst.shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext),
      this._debugID,
      'shouldComponentUpdate',
    );
  } else {
    shouldUpdate = inst.shouldComponentUpdate(
      nextProps,
      nextState,
      nextContext,
    );
  }
} else {
  if (this._compositeType === ReactCompositeComponentTypes.PureClass) {
    shouldUpdate =
      !shallowEqual(prevProps, nextProps) ||
      !shallowEqual(inst.state, nextState);
  }
}
```

So by implementing your own `shouldComponentUpdate` on a `PureComponent`, you would lose the shallow comparison.

Comment: where else can I check if my component was rendered or not ?