# Pure ReactJS Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Dan Abramov [says](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

> ...a component is pure if it is guaranteed to return the same result given the same props and state.

So if a component is supplied with the same props the same output will always be returned. This is clear.

He then says

> pure components... don’t rely on deep mutations in props or
>   state, so their rendering performance can be optimized by a shallow
>   comparison in their `shouldComponentUpdate()` hook

But this means I could supply a pure component with the same props object, but with a difference located deeper inside said props object, and the component would render the same but for different (albeit a deep difference) props. This means this constraint is not enforced.

Is declaring a component as `extends PureComponent` really saying to ReactJS "I know what I am doing. I guarantee I am using immutable state. So you need only perform shallow props comparisons in `shouldComponentUpdate`"?

Finally, `PureComponent`s provide a shallow `shouldComponentUpdate` method by default - presumably this can be overridden with whatever you want (even a deep comparison)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is declaring a component as extends PureComponent really saying to
>   ReactJS "I know what I am doing. I guarantee I am using immutable
>   state. So you need only perform shallow props comparisons in
>   shouldComponentUpdate"?

Yes

> Finally, PureComponents provide a shallow shouldComponentUpdate method
>   by default - presumably this can be overridden with whatever you want
>   (even a deep comparison)?

You can override it. React will try to [warn you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515544/can-i-use-shouldcomponentupdate-in-a-purecomponent) not to do so. In this case its better to inherit from `Component` [instead](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent).

Answer (score 1):

https://medium.com/groww-engineering/stateless-component-vs-pure-component-d2af88a1200b

```
class Welcome extends React.PureComponent {  
      render() {
        return <h1>Welcome</h1>
      }
    }

    Hello = () => {
      return <h1>Hello</h1>;
    }
```

> So above there is an example of a very simple Welcome Pure Component
>   and Hello Stateless Component. When you use these two in your Parent
>   Component, you will see Hello will re-render whenever Parent Component
>   will re-render but Welcome Component will not
>
> Also in cases where you want to use lifecycle methods of Component
>   then we have to use Pure Components as stateless components don't have
>   lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about Pure Render Checks 
https://github.com/vasanthk/react-bits/blob/master/gotchas/01.pure-render-checks.md

and good articles there :

https://flexport.engineering/optimizing-react-rendering-part-1-9634469dca02
https://flexport.engineering/optimizing-react-rendering-part-2-7b2e9a9ea21f
https://flexport.engineering/ending-the-debate-on-inline-functions-in-react-8c03fabd144